# Different responses from Flask and API Gateway

Tags: python-3.x, flask, aws-api-gateway

I am using api gateway connected to a Flask Server.

I am trying my requests in The Flask itself, and it Return `200`

When I try to test the request in aws, it also returns `200`

But when I use the api gw's endpoint, it returns - `"Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"`

The return function looks like this -

```
return Trace.MakeResponse(api_name="getStatisticsResponse",
                          trace_id=request.headers.get('Trace-Id'),
                          status="200", message="", request_json=str(request.get_json()),
                          response_json=res)
```

The response using the ip looks like a valid json -

```
{
 "documentsCount": {
 "archive": 0,
 "new": 66,
 "reported": 0
 },
 "tenantId": "005237f9-6779-4c68-89d6-d0800559d4f4"
 }
```

What can I do for this endpoint to return the same responses as the Flask itself?

Comment: Have you tried curl to the API Gateway endpoint? Can you share a snippet of the curl request and output? The error you are seeing might be related to how you are making a request to the API.

Comment: I have used  postman and got the results that you see above